# Can not click on ListView content in android application

Tags: java, android, eclipse, listview

I produced a ListView to load data from sqlite database using AssetHelper. The program works well but I want to make a clicklistener and add activity for single data of ListView content. But I can not make click on contents. I used custom adapter to list items from Sqlite.

```
ArrayList `<CustomDTO>` list = new ArrayList`<CustomDTO>`();    

CustomAdapter adapter = 
    new CustomAdapter(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.custom_search_layout,list);
listView.setClickable(false);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);

//listView click
registerForContextMenu(listView);
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {     

    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id){
        //Events
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

By calling `listView.setClickable(false);` you disabled click events for this your `listView`. Hence you cannot make clicks on the contents of it.

Answer (score 0):

Well it would be better to provide more code.

but  probably your problem is in the:
 `listView.setClickable(false);`

which disables the functionality that you want

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
listView.setClickable(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

What are you try to do with `listView.setClickable(false);`? This makes the list not clickable.

Answer (score 0):

set `listView.setClickable(true);` inorder to define rowclicks.

Comment: comment out the listView.setclickable(false) and try again.....by default the rows are clickable so no need of tat...

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everybody for your answers. I just found out that ListActivity or ListView are not clickable if there is a ImageButton in adapter.